# How to customize UIPopOver?

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

Is there a way i can remove the border from my UIPopOver ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`UIPopoverController` provides just about no method to customize its appearance. On the other hand, its behavior isn't hard to replicate, in the context you seem to be talking about—just create whatever view controller you're currently using in a popover and manually add its `view` to your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to customize the look of a UIPopoverController. You can change where it appears.  At the moment however, you cannot change the color or size of the boarder.